# SharePoint and MS Project Resource Integration

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, ms-project

I am trying to come up with an asset management solution, and it has been suggested that Project's Team Planner might be what I need.  I have looked for other ways to do this, but right now it appears that the best option is to find a way to use a Project file to manage employee and equipment scheduling.  I am at a loss, though, as to where to start.  I have seen many references to using a project task list from SharePoint to track my projects, but what about tracking resources?  I have several SP lists, such as Employees and Equipment, that all need to be tracked, but I have no idea how to go about this.  I realize this is fairly broad, and I wish I could be more specific, but I don't know enough about how the software works together to be able to give a better description.  Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The [Project Team Planner](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/project/archive/2009/10/08/project-2010-introducing-the-team-planner.aspx) looks like a feature of Project 2010 Professional that can [sync SharePoint](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/project/archive/2009/10/19/project-2010-introducing-sync-to-sharepoint.aspx) which would connect Project with SharePoint.  I don't have the system setup to help you with how it works or comment on its effectiveness.  As to how you manage existing resources in SharePoint with Project.  It really depends on the complexity of your needs.  If you only have a few people, resources and projects then Project and the Team Planner with a little SharePoint organization might be enough for you.  If you are dealing with a lot of projects then you might consider Project Server [Project Server Link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff686783%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Another option might be to use a third-party SharePoint product like a Project Site Template from BrightWork [Template Link](http://www.brightwork.com/community/free_sharepoint_project_management_template.asp?event=16#.UfGWTo3kuSo).  Though you would not have any direct connection to Project
or [Project Management Central](http://store.bamboosolutions.com/bamboomainweb/pmc-overview.aspx) from Bamboo.

Hope this helps you.

Microsoft Project 2010 Team Planner View & Microsoft Project Professional 2010 Demo
http://www.microsoft.com/global/project/en-us/RichMedia/demos/keystone/player.html?course=teamplanner

Project 2010: Introducing the Team Planner
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/project/archive/2009/10/08/project-2010-introducing-the-team-planner.aspx

Project 2010: Introducing Sync to SharePoint
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/project/archive/2009/10/19/project-2010-introducing-sync-to-sharepoint.aspx

View your team's work with Team Planner
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/project-help/view-your-team-s-work-with-team-planner-HA010373239.aspx

Project Server 2010 with SharePoint Server 2010 architecture (overview)
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff686783(v=office.14).aspx

How to Use the Team Planner to Assign Resources
http://ntrajkovski.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/how-to-use-the-team-planner-to-assign-resources/

Project 2010 Product Guide
http://download.microsoft.com/documents/France/Office/project/project-client-user-guide.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Very thorough.  As for using 3rd-party templates and such, I am not able to do this due to corporate regulations- no code (3rd-party or otherwise) can be put on the server.  As for number of projects, it's reasonable- essentially we have 60 people and around 200 pieces of equipment that are sent around the world for various stretches of time, and we want to use Project to track where they are and when.  Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like the links listed solve this problem- they simply allow you to sync the project tasks, whereas my primary concern is resources.

Comment: I think I understand you better now.  Maybe this article would provide more help.  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/project-help/use-project-with-sharepoint-HA101805393.aspx